# Are there servers that have a level limit for players?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've been looking for noob-friendly servers (since I haven't played a shooter since Q3A) and now and then I find a server that has a description hinting at noob-friendly gameplay but once in it's stuffed with lvl40+ players owning the place.

Why is it that I can't seem to search for a server with a level cap or am I supposed to believe that the matchmaking system actually works because that also drops me in similar servers.

Having no botmatches whatsoever also doesn't make it easier for new players to get to know the game mechanics without getting killed every 20 seconds.

So, is it somehow possible to search for a server that has a level cap or how would I go about getting to know the game mechanics without getting uber frustrated by high level players sucking the fun out of the game for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least [some servers](http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/173.199.108.45:25210/) that advertise themselves as catering to new players, but it's going to be a mixed bag - some of these people are likely to be experts who just want a quick way to rank up.  Level in the game doesn't always have a direct correlation to skill.

With most "realistic" shooters, you can expect a learning curve.  If this is your first realistic multiplayer shooter experience, expect to die frequently for the first few weeks.  During my first experiences with a realistic shooter I would frequently die 20 times and perhaps get one kill, even though I'd been playing first person shooters for more than a decade.  These games hinge on reflexes, knowing/having a good loadout, and frequently random luck.  I've been playing these type of shooters for several years now, and I still have frustrating rounds and plenty of WTH?!? moments.

Remember that you get points and gain experience for a wide array of activities, and in these kinds of games knowing the map is an important part of playing well.  Focus at first on things like throwing med kits and ammo boxes, and figuring out the less travelled paths so you can surprise others.  Over time you'll get the hang of it and the frustration level will decline.

Comment: Be like me and throw an ammo box out whenever you see/spawn on a friendly. 186 Resupply badges and counting... 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to find servers that actually insist on team work. (One I know of and play on is tacticalgamer.com.)

If you work as a team you don't have to be so good in the beginning and you will get better much faster than going it alone. My k/d ratio is a stunning .269 and yet when I play with a team I often do very well and sometime score in the thousands.

Understand that just being in a squad is not the same as team work. Real teams communicate constantly. They expect and provide support for each other. (The best use TeamSpeak and have server side support that put you in the proper channel with your squad.)